# Firebase - Delete a User with all related Data (iOS, Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am having problems with the deletion logic of firebase users.
The problem is: How do I delete a user and then delete all his data, when the security settings allow only authenticated users to manipulate the database?

```
NSString *userUID = user.uid;
[user deleteWithCompletion:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
      if (error) {
      }
      else {
           // Account deleted.
           [[[_ref child:@"user_info"] child:userUID] removeValue];
      }
 }];
```

In the logs:
setValue: or removeValue: at /user_info/jKXh5g1t2kbaHIqKTiz75PTGhc33 failed: permission_denied

What is the best practice here? Do I need to change the security rules or is there an appropriate code logic for this case?

I thank you for any help!

Comment: I would strongly advice against changing your security to allow unauthenticated users to delete info. Maybe you can take a look at [firebase cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion) for a solution.

Comment: Exactly, I want to maintain that security logic. Also, I want to maintain the error detection of the deleteWithCompletion: function, I do not want to delete data unless the function results in a success, i.e. I do not want to delete data beforehand. But then: this would also apply to the cloud functions implementation wouldn't it? I'd face the same problem there.

Comment: Unfortunatly I dont know anything about cloud functions myself. I can only point you in the direction of a (possible) solution.

Comment: Of course, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here.

1. The first option is to delete the user data from the database *before* the account is deleted. This means you can trigger the deletion from the app itself, so don't have the security problem.
2. The second option is to delete the user data immediately after the user account is deleted from Cloud Functions. These functions run in a trusted environment, so (using the Admin SDK) have full administrative access to your database. You'll [trigger your function when the user account is deleted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion) and clean up the database.
3. There is an entire github repo that aids in this kind of data cleanup: [user-data-protection](https://github.com/firebase/user-data-protection). It's based on the same [Cloud Functions trigger](https://github.com/firebase/user-data-protection/blob/master/functions/wipeout.js#L567) as the previous example, but covers much more extensive data cleanup in a declarative way.

Comment: Great, with the 2nd approach it works now, https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserBuilder#onDelete here is an example of the implementation.
Thanks puf!

Comment: @BesfortAbazi Are you able to show an example of how you implemented the 2nd approach?